# Unable to modify Visual Studio Configuration in command-line

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, installation, automation, command

I am trying to developp a script to automate the installation of DFIR-ORC and Visual Studio. I already installed Visual Studio by command-line using the following:

```
.\vs_Community(1).exe --addProductLang En-us --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NativeDesktop --includeRecommended --wait --quiet
```

Now I want to modify the configuration with .vsconfig from the dfir-orc repo. So I use the following commmand:

```
.\vs_Community(1).exe modify --installPath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\" --config ".\vsconfig"
```

But I have an error saying: The 'env' option in unknown. If it can help, you'll find the content of the .vsconfig file here: https://github.com/DFIR-ORC/dfir-orc/blob/main/.vsconfig

Do you have any idea ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Just in case someone is having the same issue:
This is actually related with the quotes and the path. In my case, I just modify my code to use a variable to store the path. It was just to be more responsive, but it corrected the issue (Looks like because it does not store it in a string with "").

Here's the code:

```
$currPath = $PWD.path + "\.vsconfig"

.\vs_community.exe --config $currPath --wait
```